# Can MTM get related work items and recommended tests from merged builds

Tags: tfsbuild, branching-and-merging, microsoft-test-manager

I am trying to implement the features mentioned in the title in MTM. My issue is this, our dev structure contains a feature with branches underneath. The changes get checked into those branches, which then gets merged up to the feature. The feature is then merged up with our "Main" and gets built from there. Please see below:

Main

Feature

-- Branch A

-- Branch B

-- Branch C

So we need a way to find out WHAT changed between builds. Is this possible with our current configuration and MTM? If not is there another route we can take to help extract this data?

Comment: There isn’t feature in MTM, so it is impossible. There is a related user voice https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2718306-allow-the-recommended-tests-related-work-items-li . You need to do it manually.

Comment: Let’s check whether we could achieve that through TFS API. I have some questions: 1. Did you just build the projects in Main and tests associated to Main project code or each branch have builds and tests? Which builds you want to compare or how do you want to compare builds, please provide the sample.

Comment: related work items. via the tfsapis | 
recommended tests. Yes if you have a CI enabled on the Feature branch. But if the volume of changes is large then it is not really effective and will end up showing all the tests